# IPFS cluster bootnode required after intialization

Tags: ipfs

I have a private IPFS cluster setup and I was wondering what happens to the cluster when the initial boot node that other new peer nodes are bootstrapping to is unavailable temporarily or indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only bootstrapping with a single peer, if that peer is not available, the node won't be able to bootstrap, and therefor won't be able to find other peers. If you control many peers in the cluster, simply add all of them as bootstrap peers, that way you don't have a [SPoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure).